# How do you reboot an ADO Microsoft Hosted Build Agent half way through a pipeline run and then continue the next tasks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to reboot an ADO Microsoft Build Agent halfway through a pipeline run and then continue on with the remaining tasks in that pipeline. The reason is that I need to install Hyper V on the build agent.  I can run Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All   but it won't take effect until a reboot. Therefore, a reboot after running that command is needed and then the remaining tasks (Get-VM etc) need to be completed after the reboot is finished.

Comment: You should look at running self-hosted agents as you'll be able to have a machine setup and configured with your exact specifications and enable Hypver-V ahead of time. Out of curiosity, what do you need Hyper-V for?

Comment: Thanks ... I have done self hosted agents and I would prefer to avoid that.  We are using Hyper V to create \ manage VMs that we are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not. The agent will be recycled when it shuts down. There is no way to restart the agent and continue on the same machine.

Comment: Shoot ... not what I wanted to hear but it makes sense. I guess for me to use Hyper V in my pipeline, I need to create my own build agent ... unless there is a Microsoft Hosted Agent that has Hyper V installed \ enabled.